# Difference between context.entity.Attach(entity) and context.entity.Add(entity)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm new in **Entity Framework** and when i working with **disconnected** context , i faced with a question.
What is difference between `Context.entity.Attach()` And `Context.entity.Add()`
In updating a data? 
I khow about Disconnected and
And i khow i can update a data in Entity only with getting object from database and change property with Setters and saving changes and Connected scenario in Entity
In addition i make sure that i search in all of Stack Overflow but i didn't find simple definition about this.

*Edited : 
My code without attach and add :*

```
static void update(Employee emp)
    {
        using(var context=new EmployeeCtx()))
        {
            var find=context.find(emp.id);
            find.name="new name";
            context.saveChanges();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2:**
as i realized from users that comment to my post and [Entity Framework Disconnected Scenario](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx)
`context.entity.Attach(obj)`will add entity to context with **Unchanged** state and you should add state with `context.Entry(Entity).State=EntityState.Added` but `context.entity.Add(obj)` will do this as pretty as possible
(easier to use) Thanks from who answered me and [Entity Framework Disconnected Scenario](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/attach-disconnected-entity-graph.aspx)
**Notice : this edit is for Disconnected Entity From Context**

**EDIT 3:** please read all of the comments , that is so helpful.

Comment: Do you mean EF **Core**?

Comment: @IvanStoev my means was in Ef code based

Comment: When you go to [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) documentation, you see 2 branches - "EF Core" and "EF6". The question was what EF are you using.

Comment: @IvanStoev aha sry , EF6 is my means

Comment: Hmm, EF6  `DbContext` class has no `Attach` and `Add` methods.

Comment: @IvanStoev i didn't learning this section in EfDoc i learned in some other topics and when i reading about dis context i faced with attach and then i test the code that is in my question , i saw that is work

Comment: I suspect the methods in question are DbSet.Attach and .Add, not DbContext?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro yes that was in dbset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean Code-first not code-based :)  Here's a good explanation
[Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)

Adding rewrite (plug in your dbset name and handle not found):

```
static void update(Employee emp)
{
    using(var context = new EmployeeCtx())
    {
        var currentRecord = context.<dbsetname>.First(p => p.id == emp.id);
        if (currentRecord == null)
            // Handle not found condition
        else 
        {
            currentRecord.name = emp.name;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) i am not involved with names :D but thanks I'll edit comment

Comment: Ok i read that answer . There is a question : doc said if Entity state is not tracked by context you should using attach. So i have to check Entity State whenever i want to update Entity??

Comment: Add if new, Attach if existing entity you updated while detached.  After Attach, use <yourcontext>.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges() as the preferred way to update ModelState before save.

Comment: Aha got it and thanks. Another question : look at my code ; is there difference in process time between my code and what you said?

Comment: Add & Attach refer to the in-memory context/change tracking.  I added a small rewrite.  Bypasses need for playing with Attach, etc.  Retrieve existing record and only update what is needed.

Comment: The "why" is that only the fields which I am allowing to be updated can be updated.

Comment: DetectChanges() is called upon SaveChanges automatically (by default), so it does not do anything good (especially since in disconnected scenario, the tracked changed are usually incomplete). the entity state is updated by changetracker whenever an attached entry is different from the state at the time it was first attached. In this case DetectChanges() will set the entity state accordingly. Neither Added, deleted, modified nor unchanged entity states can be set correctly in disconnected scenario using DetectChanges().

Comment: @DevilSuichiro what about context.Entry().state=EntityState.[added,modified,..] is it change state correctly?

Comment: this call sets the entity state manually without the use of ChangeTracking. The entity state is used by EF to determine what kind of SQL statement (INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE) to create for this entry and is updated automatically in connected scenario (most of the time) by EF itself.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro i khow that state changes is easy in connected , but in disconnected scen i tried the ways but always entity stayed at unchanged

Comment: That's true. To set the entity state to added, you'll either have to attach and set the entity state to added, or add the entity to the DbSet (which will set the entry and all navigational properties to added). To set the entity state to modified, you'll either have to attach and set the entity state to modified, or attach the object and set all properties that are different from the time you retrieved the object.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro compeletly understand. But when i see to some samples , i see most of developers dont attention to state in disconnected scenario what happened if we don't update states???

Comment: most developers use a semi-connected scenario. if you do not update the states in entirely disconnected scenario, the only updates you'll send to the database are insert statements.